# server side code for reminder in Lagom Scala

Tags: scala, push-notification, lagom

how to implement push notification for android, ios, web. Actually, I am new in Software development and do not have any idea. currently, I am using CQRS and event sourcing in Lagom framework with scala.

Comment: [ask] check ou this link.

Answer (score 0):

You should subscribe clients by AKKA `server sent events` feature and send notification to them by AKKA `event bus` feature.

please read these two articles to find your way.

- [AKKA server sent events](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/sse-support.html)
- [AKKA event bus](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.20/event-bus.html)